# Ширина Flexbox по ширине flex-элементов

Tags: css, flexbox

Народ, есть вопрос. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы flex-коробка не растягивалась на всю ширину родительского элемента, а подстраивалась под ширину дочерних? В примере видно, что несмотря на наличие во флекс-боксе всего двух слов, он сам растягивается на максимум.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  background: antiquewhite;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.flexbox {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: antiquewhite;
  padding: 1em;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```